# Grub auto fixer

Tags: windows-7, linux, debian, grub

I have managed to kill Grub by upgrading windows (to windows 7) after installing linux, debian.
Now i still had a spare blank partition,
so i put on some pc-bsd, thinking it would havbe a decent bootloader (proably grub) but it didn't.
so i removed that installed mandriva.
Now grub lets me access mandriva, and windows. 
And i can select debian and see the old grub,
but debain doesn't work.

Any tools that I can simple burn to disk that will remove all old boot loaders and create a new one?

btw 64bit processer and OS's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please be more specific.

"And I can select debian and see the old grub, but debian doesn't work."

What exactly happens when you choose debian and try to boot it?

If you have a digital camera and a small tripod you can use that to capture pics of the various screens as it tries to boot so you don't have to memorize and re-type everything.

Please let us know; this is crucial for helping you.

-pbr

Answer (score 2):

I've used with success before the [Grub Super Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/), which works quite well.  It will install Grub for you.   Alternately, you can use [SysRescCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/) which I have also used successfully in the past.  It has both 32-bit and 64-bit modes, and but usually I end up chrooting into my old system after mounting it up and using that.  Just remember to mount the /dev partition into the filesystem first, or grub-install won't be able to find your drives!